# Change of json format

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json format as below.

```
var calltypes = [{"label":"ABC","y":2},{"label":"XYZ","y":10}, .......]
```

I need to use it as below in javascript.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
  ['ABC', 2],
  ['XYZ', 10],
  ...........
]);
```

Can someone please help me in this?

I have tried as below as hardcoding it. But I need to use calltypes JSON in variable data.

```
var rowIter = 1;
    var calltypes = [];
            var keys = Object.keys(result);         
            for (var index in keys){
                 var type = result[keys[index]];
                 var row = {"label":keys[index],"y":type.length};
                  calltypes.push(row);

            }
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML += "CallTypes @@ " + JSON.stringify(calltypes);


  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
  ['ABC', 2],
  ['XYZ', 10]
]);
```

As @Rahul suggested below, I have tried to modify my whole code as below.

```
    function createChart(result){
            var rowIter = 1;
            var calltypes = [];
                    var keys = Object.keys(result);         
                    for (var index in keys){
                         var type = result[keys[index]];
                         var row = {"label":keys[index],"y":type.length};
                         // document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML += "Row@@ @@ " + JSON.stringify(row);
                         calltypes.push(row);

                    }
                    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML += "CallTypes @@ " + JSON.stringify(calltypes);
                    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML += " @@ calltypes.length @@ " + JSON.stringify(calltypes.length);
var mapData = [];
            for(var index = 0; index < calltypes.length; index++) {
            var eachRow = calltypes[index];
            // collect the data in desired format
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML += "eachRow @@ " + JSON.stringify(eachRow);
            mystring = eachRow.label;
            newTemp = mystring.replace(/"/g, "'");
            mapData.push([newTemp, eachRow.y]);
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML += " @@ MapData @@ " + JSON.stringify(mapData);
            }
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML += " @@ MapData1 @@ " + JSON.stringify(mapData);


            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(mapData);

            // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart

      var options = {'title':'Distribution by Hooks', 'width':550, 'height':400};

      // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
      chart.draw(data, options);

        }
```

mapData getting printed fine but the Piechart ultimately not showing up.

Comment: What have you tried so far? just iterate over JSON array to prepre array of array?

Comment: Just now I have updated my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the many ways to do it-

JavaScript Code:

```
var A1 = [
    {"label": "Task", "y": "Hours per Day"},
    {"label": "ABC","y" :2},
    {"label": "XYZ","y": 10}
];

var mapData = [];
// iterate over JSON array
for(var index = 0; index < A1.length; index++) {
    var eachRow = A1[index];
    // collect the data in desired format
    mapData.push([eachRow.label, eachRow.y]);
}

// print the value
console.log("mapData: ", JSON.stringify(mapData));

// use this variable directly in your code
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(mapData);
```

Output:

> mapData:  [["Task","Hours per Day"],["ABC",2],["XYZ",10]]

Comment: Thanks! But how do I feed it here?  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable();

Comment: Simply pass the variable to your visualization `var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(mapData);`